# GlView causes OpenGL error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am new in cocos2d.I am making a gaming with uiview with cocos2d(3.0 Beta) platform.I set a GLView in custom viewcontroller. Below is my code.

```
 - (void)setupCocos2D {

        CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:self.view.bounds pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 depthFormat:0];**

       glView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [self.view insertSubview:glView atIndex:0];

       [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setView:glView];**

    }
```

It's working fine.But when we put on object then give me Following **Memory worning.**

```
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 544
OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[CCGLView swapBuffers] 287**
```

I think when we call `([[CCDirector sharedDirector] setView:glView])` setView method it's not find CCDirector method but UIView method.I can't Access the CCDirector method.Same Method I also can't call in AppDelegate class.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

  //openGLView is now (setView in Latest version).It's Can't Access here.**

  [[director openGLView] removeFromSuperview];
    [director end];
}
```

Comment: it's an opengl error, not a memory warning. What you do to setup cocos2d doesn't look right at all. I don't think autoresizing is supported yet. Did you know that director is a viewcontroller?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D ya.it's opengl error.I don't need Autorisizing.every thing is display fine.But when we add sprite object then error generate.Some time Performance is so much decrease.I am not tested in Device. Thanx for your replay.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D my code is working fine in 2.0 but not working in 3.0 version.

Comment: Maybe stick to 2.0 since 3.0 is still alpha and most certainly will contain bugs.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thank you Sir for your replay.So,I think this stage better for me use 2.0 instead of 3.0 ? and latest 3.0 Beta also release but that into not contain install.sh(setup file).

Comment: one more things sir,I am studying your tutorial.That's very good.Thank you for your support..........

Answer (score 0):

You use below Code in setupCocos2D

```
 - (void)setupCocos2D
 {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];

    UIWindow *window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    [window_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                   depthFormat:0
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:NO];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];



    //  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change this setting at any time.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];


 }
```

Comment: i tried that.My project is fine working in 2.0 but not working in Latest cocos2d 3.0 Alpha version.